# How to improve security of local Snowflake user accounts (not connected to SSO/MFA) used for ongoing, daily processes (eg Tableau scheduled extracts)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a local Snowflake user account that is used for scheduled processes, like Tableau connections, etc. Regular Snowflake users have their own credentials that tie back to SSO/MFA systems (note: the SSO/MFA is NOT Snowflake's native SSO/MFA functionality.) I use the local user account to take advantage of scheduling and automation of SQL statements in external systems (e.g. Tableau), to avoid needing to MFA every time a connection is made or query is executed.

I would like to enhance the security measures around this local account, since it is not safeguarded by the SSO/MFA architecture that protects individual Snowflake users. Currently the only option that I have found is to create a Snowflake network policy that is assigned to the local user account, restricting to only the IP ranges that external systems call from.

What other options are there to secure these local user accounts?

Comment: I'd recommend using a key-pair authentication method for a local user account that is only leveraged from a single machine.  That'll be a bit more secure than using a straight password.

Comment: Some applications can also leverage OAuth to your SSO provider and handle the token management for you.

Answer (score 0):

The below article will help you with all the security measures available in Snowflake, along with best practices.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-Security-Overview-and-Best-Practices